# I get an error running Lippia example with Samsung mobile container

Tags: docker, mobile, automation, automated-tests

I've been trying to run the lippia example from mobile, using docker,
but when I execute docker-compose up, I run into an error in the samsung_s7_9.0 conainer.

I´m using a linux Kubuntu

I get the following error:

````
Pablo@Pablo-Kubuntu:~/Escritorio/Crowdar/Lippia/MOBILE/Lippia-mobile-sample-project$ sudo docker-compose up
WARNING: The apkDirectory variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Creating network "lippia-mobile-sample-project_default" with the default driver
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_selenium_hub-mobile-apk_1 ... done
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_nginx_web-sample_1        ... done
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_jenkins-mobile_apk_1      ... done
Creating lippia-mobile-sample-project_samsung_s7_9.0_1          ... error

ERROR: for lippia-mobile-sample-project_samsung_s7_9.0_1  Cannot create container for service samsung_s7_9.0: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters

ERROR: for samsung_s7_9.0  Cannot create container for service samsung_s7_9.0: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this `docker-compose` you must send the argument `${apkDirectory}`. Use this argument to test the application you have.
In order to test the app that comes in that example project you can use the following command:

> apkDirectory=./sample_apk docker-compose up

To send the arguments, type before the command `(apkDirectory=sample_apk)`, this value is the name of the `directory` which is in the sample project
and contains the `.apk files`.

In the case you are trying to test another apk, you can use the `directory` of your `local pc` that contains the apk and refer to the name
of the apk in the project pom.

For example if your application is in: `/opt/apk/app.apk` you use the command:

> apkDirectory=/opt/apk docker-compose up

In the project pom you must change the address of the application to:

> <crowdar.appLocation>/root/tmp/sample_apk/app.apk</crowdar.appLocation>

This is because the `volume` pointed it's in your local directory with the container's path `/root/tmp/sample_apk` directory.